# Is it possible to create a chrome extension to intercept what user type in the browser search bar before redirect?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension to forward to different url based on keywords.

For example

If user type in search bar in the browser "facebook joe" or "linkedin joe, the chrome extension could help to forward to "facebook.com/joe" or "linkedin/in/joe" respectively.

How am I able to know what user type in the browser search bar in my chrome extension in order for me to do this forwarding ? Or what chrome api I need to use ?

**The sequence of what I want to create is**

1. User type some thing in the browser search bar
2. User click enter
3. The chrome extension will check if it is a keyword
4. If it is a keyword, redirect it accordingly
5. Otherwise, it do nothing and just go through the default behavior

Answer (score -1):

Try `webRequest` as the following example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    const redirectUrl = YourUrlCorrectionFunction(details.url);
    return {redirectUrl: redirectUrl};
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Refer:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest